# How to register MemberSubstitution when using ByteBuddy Maven plug-in?

Tags: java, maven, byte-buddy

I'd like to use a `MemberSubstitution` to rewrite accesses to a particular field. For this I'd like to implement a `Plugin` to apply this change at compile time using the ByteBuddy Maven plug-in. How can I register the substitution in this case?

Update to give some more context:

Here's the class I'd like to modify:

```
public class Foo {

    private final String FOO = "FOO!";
    private final String BAR = "BAR!";

    public String test() {
        return FOO;
    }
}
```

Here's my `Plugin`:

```
public class HookInstallingPlugin implements Plugin {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(TypeDescription target) {
        return target.getName().equals("Foo");
    }

    @Override
    public Builder<?> apply(Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassFileLocator classFileLocator) {
        Field f = null;
        try {
            f = Class.forName("com.example.foo.Foo").getDeclaredField("BAR");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        builder = builder.visit(MemberSubstitution.strict()
                .field(ElementMatchers.named("FOO"))
                .onRead()
                .replaceWith(f)
                .on(named("test")));

        return builder;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
    }
```

I'd expect `test()` to return "BAR!", but it actually returns "FOO!", and this is confirmed when examining the byte code using javap. The type isn't altered, but I can canform that the `apply()` method was run.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin has two methods:

1. `matches` determines what types to instrument.
2. `apply` instruments thos types. It provides a `DynamicType.Builder` to register your changes.

A `MemberSubstitution` is a decorator, not a replacement for methods. Thus it is registered via the `visit` method on the `DynamicType.Builder`:

```
builder = builder.visit(MemberSubstitution.strict().field(...).onWrite().stub().on(...));
```

This would for example remove all field writes of matched fields in all methods within the supplied matcher in the last argument.

Comment: Thanks, so my transformation is applied now. But `strict()` results in this exception when running the plug-in: Could not resolve java.lang.System using net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default@ab7633af. Wondering whether I'm doing something stupid here.

Comment: I've simplified my instrumented method for now to avoid the type pool issue above, but for some reason the type still doesn't get modified. I've updated the example in the question with some more context.

Comment: It is because the field is never read, you created a compile-time constant (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) where the field-access is substituted by a direct copy of that constant. There is no trace in the byte code that the value is from this field. I'd need to have a look at the other error.

Comment: The other you are seeing is a bug, I'll fix it in the next release.

Comment: should I file a bug report for that exception? Or do you already have one I can track?